# Close modal with jquery inside tag html

Tags: jquery, html, button, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Can I close modal with jquery inside of tag html? I'm using code like below but it doesn't work

```
<button class="circle btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="$(this).dialog('close')">X</button>
```

More my code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal7" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button class="circle btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="$('#myModal7').dialog('close'); ">X</button>
    <br>
        <form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/account_c/uploadPDF" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; padding-top: 30px;"><span>Certificate Name</span>                
            <input type="text" name="certificateName" class="form-control" placeholder="Certificate Name" required></p>
            <p style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; padding-top: 30px;"><span>Upload File</span>
            <input type="file" name="pdffile" id="fileUpload" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse" required></p>
            <img src=# id="view" alt="your image" style="display:none; width:88px; height:88px; padding-left: 30px;">
            <p style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; padding-top: 30px;"><input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload2" class="btn btn-info" style=" color:white; " value="Upload"></p>
        </form>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close dialog this way. Change `dialogID` with the id of your dialog box

```
<button class="circle btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="$('#dialogid').dialog('close')">X</button>
```

Comment: here is the working jsfiddle with your given html code `https://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/wbqswo7o/` Try it